# Ansible error: with_items expects a list or a set

Tags: ansible

Here is the Ansible source code where with_items is linked to a dictionary type variable named `"grafana_datasource_body"`. I always get an error message `"ith_items expects a list or a set"`. Here is the source code and related output.

**Ansible source code :**

```
- name: Configure datasource creation http body
  set_fact:
    grafana_datasource_body:
      name: "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_Name}}"
      type: "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_Type}}"
      isDefault: "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_IsDefault}}"
      access: "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_Access}}"
      basicAuth: "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_BasicAuth}}"
      url: "{{InfluxDB_Server}}:{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_Http_Port}}"
      database: "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_Db}}"
      username: "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_DbUser}}"
      password: "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_DbPassword}}"
  when: Ass_grafana_Datasource_Name not in grafana_datasources_output.json|map(attribute='name')|list

- debug: msg="Datasource creation http body = {{grafana_datasource_body}}"
  when: Ass_grafana_Datasource_Name not in grafana_datasources_output.json|map(attribute='name')|list

# Create non existing datasources
- name: datasource > Create datasource
  register: grafana_datasources_create_output
  failed_when: "'Datasource added' not in grafana_datasources_create_output|to_json"
  uri:
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:{{Ass_grafana_Listen_Http_Port}}/api/datasources"
    method: POST
    HEADER_Content-Type: application/json
    body: '{{ item|to_json }}'
    force_basic_auth: true
    user: "{{Ass_grafana_Api_User}}"
    password: "{{Ass_grafana_Api_Password}}"
    status_code: 200
  with_items: "{{grafana_datasource_body}}"
  when: item.name not in grafana_datasources_output.json|map(attribute='name')|list
```

**Output**

```
TASK: [./grafana/grafana_Role | Configure datasource creation http body] ******
<10.0.20.7> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
ok: [10.0.20.7] => {"ansible_facts": {"grafana_datasource_body": {"access": "proxy", "basicAuth": "false", "database": "webcom-int", "isDefault": "true", "name": "MonTonton", "password": "webcom", "type": "influxdb", "url": "http://localhost:8086", "username": "webcom"}}}

TASK: [./grafana/grafana_Role | debug msg="Datasource creation http body = {{grafana_datasource_body}}"] ***
<10.0.20.7> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
ok: [10.0.20.7] => {
"msg": "Datasource creation http body = {'username': u'webcom', 'name': u'MonTonton', 'database': u'webcom-int', 'url': u'http://localhost:8086', 'basicAuth': u'false', 'access': u'proxy', 'password': u'webcom', 'type': u'influxdb', 'isDefault': u'true'}"
}

TASK: [./grafana/grafana_Role | datasource > Create datasource] ***************
fatal: [10.0.20.7] => with_items expects a list or a set

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: Fix copy-paste indentation issues in your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Any real reason to use `with_items` loop here?

Replace

```
with_items: "{{grafana_datasource_body}}"
```

with

```
with_items: "{{ [grafana_datasource_body] }}"
```

this will work.

But you can use `body: '{{ grafana_datasource_body|to_json }}'` and don't use `with_items`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is better but still not working beacuse I cannot properly populate a dictionnary with the set_fact command.

Comment: Here is the output when trying to populate the grafana_datasource_body. Does not look like a dictionary and there in an extra 'u' character ?

Comment: TASK: [./grafana/grafana_Role | debug msg="Datasource creation http body = {{grafana_datasource_body}}"] *** 
<10.0.20.7> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
ok: [10.0.20.7] => {
    "msg": "Datasource creation http body = {'username': u'webcom', 'name': u'MonTonton', 'database': u'webcom-int', 'url': u'http://localhost:8086', 'basicAuth': u'false', 'access': u'proxy', 'password': u'webcom', 'type': u'influxdb', 'isDefault': u'true'}"

Comment: Looks like a dict, just a python representation.

Comment: You are right. Looks like a dict indeed. The pb is with the boolean variables basicAuth & isDefault. They are populated as string in the dict. When I force them to true or false (not using dymaic variable such as "{{Ass_grafana_Datasource_BasicAuth}}"), the remote http server properly handles the http request

Comment: Looks like Ansible issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5463